# Неточные показания датчика dht22

Tags: arduino

Прогал компактную метеостанцию на dht22,при выводе показаний на монитор порта показывает очень странные показания не соответствующие реальности,пробовал разные библиотеки,не спасло.

```
#include <GyverTM1637.h>
#include <TinyDHT.h>
#define CLK 3
#define DIO 4
#define DHTPIN 2
#define DHTTYPE DHT22

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE); 
#define TEMPTYPE 1 
GyverTM1637 disp(CLK, DIO);
void setup() {
  
  disp.clear();
  disp.brightness(7);  // яркость, 0 - 7 (минимум - максимум)
  Serial.begin(115200);
  dht.begin();  // Initialize DHT Teperature Sensor
  
}

void loop() {
    float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
           
 if ( t == BAD_TEMP || h == BAD_HUM ) { // if error conditions          
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT");
  } else {
    Serial.print("Humidity: "); 
    Serial.print(h);
    Serial.print(" %\t");
    Serial.print("Temperature: "); 
    Serial.print(t);
    Serial.println(" *C");
  }
 
 disp.displayInt(h);
  

}
```

Не обращайте внимание на команды для экранчика)
[image: скриншот показаний датчика]

[image: еще фото подключения]
[image: фото подключения]

[image: dht22]

[image: шарик внутри dht22]

Comment: Покажите схему подключения, как минимум, а еще лучше и фото.

Comment: gnd в gnd,vcc в 3.3v dat в D2

Comment: Если оставить только TinyDHT - проблема остается?

Comment: @gbg ,к сожалению да, думал проблема в макетке,распаял все равно влажность до 255 зашкаливает,а температура не отражает действительность(прикладывал к холодному окну,где явно температура меньше 10 градусов,а он показывает 25)

Comment: Согласно даташиту, должен быть резистор-подтяжка  10к между линией DATA и +5V. На ваших фото его нет.

Comment: @gbg "Датчик DHT часто продается в виде готового модуля. В этом случае он имеет три вывода и подключается без резистора, т.к. резистор уже есть на плате." источник: http://edurobots.ru/2015/02/arduino-dlya-nachinayushhix-urok-9-podklyuchenie-datchika-temperatury-i-vlazhnosti-dht11-i-dht22/

Comment: @Николай даже под теми углами, что у вас снято, я не вижу на плате резистора. Возможно, он там есть, а может его и нет - нужны другие ракурсы.

Comment: @gbg добавил фото модуля, пока фотографировал заметил странный шарик внутри модуля, он просто катается туда сюда, веротно модуль бракованный, сейчас попробую рассмотреть откуда он мог отваливаться...

Comment: разобрал dht 22, инородное тело извлек , свиду все хорошо

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "DHT.h"
#define DHTPIN 2
#define DHTTYPE DHT22

float temp2=0;
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    dht.begin();
}

void loop()
{
    delay(2000);
    float h = dht.readHumidity();
    float t = dht.readTemperature();
    if (isnan(h) || isnan(t)) {
        Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
        return;
    }
    
    Serial.print("Humidity: ");
    Serial.print(h);
    Serial.print(" %\t");
    Serial.print("Temperature: ");
    if (t > 1000){ temp2 = (t - 3276.7); } else{ temp2 = t; }
    Serial.print(temp2);
    Serial.println(" *C ");
}
```

Вопрос был решен полным переписыванием кода, включая переустановку библиотек. А так же, извлечением металлического шарика из корпуса сенсора. При показании отрицательной температуры показывает -3276, строчка с if призвана это решить (но не решает).